# Calendar notification - no sound

Tags: notifications, 7.0-nougat, calendar

On Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 with MIUI 10, Android 7 there is no way to enable sound for calendar notifications, I get vibrations only. I have tried several calendar apps including Google, MIUI, aCalendar+, various settings including setting battery optimisation off but it never plays a sound, it only vibrates.

When I press TEST in aCalendar+ notifications settings it vibrates but makes no sound and provides no further help. Of course my sounds are on and I have even tried to turn off bluetooth. I have no SD card, all sounds are stored in internal memory.

Notifications form WhatsApp or Facebook messenger work well with the sound.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out by browsing and reviewing all available settings.

There is an entry **Notifications and status bar** under **System & Devices** menu.
There is an entry **App notifications** and I have enabled everything for *aCalendar+* there. Now notifications come with sound finally.

Those settings are quite complicated especially for former Windows Phone users where such stuff worked out of the box.

[A good article about the problem is here](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-fix-push-notifications-miui-8).